# MySQL 8.0 - SELECT QUERY

Tags: select, query, mysql-workbench

Hi I am having trouble with building a select query command with my tables.

**TABLE CUSTOMER**

```
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| customer_number | customer_status | order_status |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|     196         |      unpaid     |    served    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|     197         |      unpaid     |  unserved    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|     198         |       paid      |    served    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

**TABLE CUSTOMER_ORDERS**

```
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| cust_ord_number | customer_number | order_status |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       350       |       196       |  preparing   |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       351       |       196       |   pending    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       352       |       197       |   pending    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       353       |       197       |   pending    |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       354       |       198       |   prepared   |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       355       |       198       |   prepared   |
+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

What I want is to `select` all the `customer_number` whose `customer_status` is unpaid and `order_status` is unserved from `table customer` and the customer_number must not have its `order_status` `preparing` or `prepared` from `customer_orders`.

Basically I need to select all customer_number that is unpaid and unserve and must not have preparing or prepared.

Im sorry if I did not explain it well, any answers will help thanks.

Comment: It means that if all of the orders of the customer where completed or prepared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN customer_orders co 
    ON c.customer_number = co.customer_number 
   AND co.order_status IN ('preparing', 'prepared')
WHERE c.customer_status='unpaid'
  AND c.order_status = 'unserved'
  AND co.cust_ord_number IS NULL
```